# Происхождение выражения "голод не тётка"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "голод не тётка"?

Comment: В 30х годах, в советах, "Теткой" называли народный комитет внутренних дел. Может есть связь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это сокращение от пословицы "Голод не тетка, пирожка не подсунет".

Answer (score 2):

Это действительно сокращение от указанной пословицы, но смысл её не совсем понятен без комментария. "Пирожка не поднесет" часто трактуют как "не пожалеет", "пощады от него не жди" и т.п. Трудно понять, чем объясняется такое толкование.

На самом деле всё проще. "Пирожка не поднесет" означает, что голодный будет есть, что дадут, а не ждать "пирожков" и прочих разносолов. Короче: "проголодаешься — всё сожрёшь". Примерно так.

(+)
Возможно будет интересно, что я какое-то время назад попытался найти первоисточник первого из названных толкований, того, что по моему мнению неправильное. И не нашел. Видимо, чисто народное, по простому воспринятое.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё: Голод не тетка, брюхо не лукошко / Голод не тетка, душа не сосед, Голод не тетка, заставит заговорить / Голод не тетка, заставит работать / Голод не тетка, калачика не подложит, и т.д.

В основном, это обращение к юным протестного возраста особам, настаивающих на признании за ними таких прав и такими способами, которые загоняют их же в тупик. И в других категориях граждан таких хватает. Реакция родных на их обиду выражена в такой фразе (слыхивал в свой адрес): губы толще — брюхо тоньше.